# What is the alternative for using Activator.CreateInstance() method?

Tags: reflection, .net-assembly, c#-5.0, activator, webconfigurationmanager

I am creating an object of the logger type dynamically, trying to use the concept of Reflection. My code is as follows.

```
public static ILogger Create(string loggerType)
{
            ILogger logger = null;

            string loggerValue = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(loggerType);
            string[] loggerDll = loggerValue.Split(',');
            string[] loggerTypeValue = loggerDll[0].Split('.');

            Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(loggerTypeValue[0]);
            Type type = asm.GetType(loggerDll[1]);

            logger = (ILogger)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            return logger;
}
```

I want to drop the use of Activator.CreateInstance() method. What is the alternative choice for me?

Comment: For what reason do you want to drop `Activator.CreateInstance` ?

Comment: @YK1 That's because I have read that it's used with marshaling and it creates a wrapper object that isn't equal to the original object.

Comment: That is true for the `CreateInstance` overloads  which return `ObjectHandle`, however, the overload you are using above returns `Object`. SO, I don't think you have to worry about it.